# Pull data of orders having non-zero subtotal for each customer

Tags: magento-1, sql

I want the count of the orders which each customer has placed. Only those order which has non-zero subtotal should be counted. How can I get that data? Please let me know if we can use any SQL query

I have fetched data through query but it gives a count of all the orders, whereas I want only those orders which have non - zero value

```
$sql_results = "SELECT
    CONCAT(FORMAT(SUM(sales_flat_order.`grand_total`), 2)) AS 'Lifetime_Sales',
    COUNT(sales_flat_order.entity_id) AS 'Orders',
    customer_entity.email AS 'Email',
    customer_entity_varchar.value AS 'name',
    customer_address_entity_varchar.value AS 'Mobile'
FROM `customer_entity`
    LEFT JOIN sales_flat_order ON customer_entity.entity_id = sales_flat_order.customer_id
    LEFT JOIN customer_entity_varchar ON customer_entity.entity_id = customer_entity_varchar.entity_id
    LEFT JOIN customer_address_entity ON customer_entity.entity_id = customer_address_entity.parent_id
    LEFT JOIN customer_address_entity_varchar ON customer_address_entity.entity_id = customer_address_entity_varchar.entity_id
    WHERE customer_entity_varchar.attribute_id = 986 AND customer_address_entity_varchar.attribute_id = 17
GROUP BY customer_entity.entity_id
ORDER BY SUM(sales_flat_order.`grand_total`) DESC
LIMIT 10000 OFFSET 0";
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by myself only. I had to put a condition of grand total greater than zero in where clause something like this

```
WHERE customer_entity_varchar.attribute_id = 986 AND customer_address_entity_varchar.attribute_id = 17 AND sales_flat_order.grand_total > 0
```